# how to add ctrl+click event on special String in java editor

Tags: eclipse

in java editor, i hope that after pressed CTRL, when moving the mouse to a special String, like "@image//imagepath", the ctrl+hover event can be detected. and how to develop the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an Eclipse plugin which uses the hyperlink extension point to contribute to Java editor: see http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_hyperlinkDetectors.html . Then you have to package this plugin in an Eclipse p2 repository so you can install it in any Eclipse IDE.